# How to plot a trend line in a scatter plot from multiple dataframe data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have 4 data frames, which are `df, df1, df2` and `df3`.I have plotted these data into a scatter plot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
x1 = df['x'].loc['2020-01-01 00:00':'2020-01-01 00:59']
y1 = df1['y']
plt.scatter(x1, y1)

x2 = df['x'].loc['2020-01-01 01:00':'2020-01-01 01:59']
y2 = df2['y']
plt.scatter(x2, y2)

x3 = df['x'].loc['2020-01-01 02:00':'2020-01-01 02:59']
y3 = df3['y']
plt.scatter(x3, y3)
```

To plot trend line, I use the below code found in stackoverflow.

```
 z = np.polyfit(x1, y1, 1)
    p = np.poly1d(z)
    plt.plot(x1,p(x1))
plt.show()
```

However, this only gives the trendline from `df1`. I would like to plot a trendline which includes the data from `df1, df2 and df3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses data only from `df1`, as you send only the `df1` to the code which plots your trend.

something like:

```py
x_full = x1.append(x2).append(x3)
y_full = y1.append(y2).append(y3)

z = np.polyfit(x_full, y_full , 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x_full, p(x_full))
plt.show()
```

but please check documentation on how you append series, i.e. `y1,y2,y3` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html